# How can i format a string as currency in a data bound DataGrid in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, string-formatting

I have some data being shown in a DataGrid.  The data comes from SQL, where a "money" type can be null.  When i display this data, all is OK when i format the data in a double column format as currency.  ie:

internal void FillGrid()
        {

```
        bD = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt = EmployerQuery();  //queries the SQL DB


        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmployerName", typeof(string)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FlatMinAmount", typeof(double)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DistrictRate", typeof(double)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("VendorRate", typeof(double)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        bD.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("EmployeeCount", typeof(int)));

        foreach (DataRow sqlRow in dt.Rows)
        {
            var row = bD.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = sqlRow["ClientID"];
            row["EmployerName"] = sqlRow["OfficialName"];
            row["FlatMinAmount"] = sqlRow["FlatMinAmount"];
            row["DistrictRate"] = sqlRow["DistrictRate"];
            row["VendorRate"] = sqlRow["VendorRate"];
            row["Description"] = sqlRow["Description"];
            row["EmployeeCount"] = sqlRow["EmployeeCount"];

            bD.Rows.Add(row);

        }
```

However, I then save the data as a .csv file.  When i read that file back, the values for "FlatMinAmount" that were null are not allowed to be inserted into a column type double, so I cannot format the data columns as type double, since many are null.

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="newGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=readGrid, Path=readGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                 Margin="5" Height="175" Width="Auto" ColumnWidth="Auto">
        <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}" Header="Employer ID" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmployerName}" Header="Employer Name" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FlatMinAmount, StringFormat=C}" Header="FlatMinAmount" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DistrictRate, StringFormat=C}" Header="District Rate" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding VendorRate, StringFormat=C}" Header="Vendor Rate" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Description}" Header="Description" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding EmployeeCount}" Header="EmployeeCount" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dg:DataGrid>


DataTable r = new DataTable();

        try
        {
            //string csv = string.Empty;

            //r.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            //r.Columns.Add("EmployerName", typeof(string));
            //r.Columns.Add("FlatMinAmount",typeof(double));
            //r.Columns.Add("DistrictRate", typeof(double));
            //r.Columns.Add("VendorRate", typeof(double));
            //r.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
            //r.Columns.Add("EmployeeCount", typeof(int));

            r.Columns.Add("ID");
            r.Columns.Add("EmployerName");
            r.Columns.Add("FlatMinAmount");
            r.Columns.Add("DistrictRate");
            r.Columns.Add("VendorRate");
            r.Columns.Add("Description");
            r.Columns.Add("EmployeeCount");

            // Read sample data from CSV file
            using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
            {
                CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
                while (reader.ReadRow(row))
                {
                    //foreach (string s in row)
                    {
                        r.Rows.Add(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6]);


                    }

                }
            }
```

(readGrid is then set to r in code-behind)

If they are string, then i cannot use the StringFormat=C in the binding to show $ etc.  Also, it seems I cannot style a DataGridTextColumn.  So, how can i display the values I read in from .csv as $xx.xx?

Comment: If the value is null then how does row["FlatMinAmount"] = sqlRow["FlatMinAmount"]; not fail?

Comment: you tell me.  apparently, when it gets it from SQL, the type is System.DBNull and it allows it to be inserted into the column?

Comment: `DataColumn` by default allows values of `System.DBNull`

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking DataReader that has different behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the number is null, can't you just set the value of the column to DBNull?

```
row["FlatMinAmount"] = DBNull.Value;
```

Here's a little console app I ran to show this working:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Blah", typeof(double));
            tbl.Columns.Add(col);

            DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
            row["Blah"] = DBNull.Value;

            Console.WriteLine("Result: " + row["Blah"].ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up checking each value for null and if it was null, then setting the row's corresponding value to DBNull.Value.  I would like to know why I can set a row of type double to DBNull.Value, but not to null.

Comment: `DataColumn` by default allows values of `System.DBNull`. However `null != System.DBNull.Value` so you cannot assign null to it - unless the column type is a nullable type.

Answer (score 0):

use `Double.Parse()` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.parse.aspx to format the value when you read it in.  This will allow you to use double and you can then apply the appropriate formatting for output.

Updated:
The issue you seem to be having that when reading from file the value is `null` and when reading from database it is `DBNull`.  By default `DataTable` allows for `DBNull` values.  If you want to mimic this for read, try the following

```
    DataTable r = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        r.Columns.Add("ID");
        r.Columns.Add("EmployerName");
        r.Columns.Add("FlatMinAmount");
        r.Columns.Add("DistrictRate");
        r.Columns.Add("VendorRate");
        r.Columns.Add("Description");
        r.Columns.Add("EmployeeCount");

        // Read sample data from CSV file
        using (CsvFileReader reader = new CsvFileReader(filename))
        {
            CsvRow row = new CsvRow();
            while (reader.ReadRow(row))
            {
                //foreach (string s in row)
                {
                    double d;
                    double? val2 = null;
                    double? val3 = null;
                    double? val4 = null;
                    if (Double.TryParse(row[2], out d)) val2 = d;
                    if (Double.TryParse(row[3], out d)) val3 = d;
                    if (Double.TryParse(row[4], out d)) val4 = d;

                    r.Rows.Add(row[0], row[1], val2, val3, val4, row[5], row[6]);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: `Double.TryParse()`? if the operation fails then the value is null or Not a Number (NAN).

Comment: I don't think you are seeing the problem.  I know it is null.  I can't insert a null into a column of type double by definition, since double is a value type.

Comment: See updated code - if the value is null and you can test it with `Double.TryParse()` then you can assign null value instead of what is read.

Comment: thanks Kami.  i just had to set the values to DBNull.Value (not null, that's what they already were!) if they were null when read in.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TargetNullValue` attribute:

```
<dg:DataGridTextColumn Binding=""{Binding FlatMinAmount,TargetNullValue='Not Specified',StringFormat=C}" Header="FlatMinAmount" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Comment: i assume the double quotes before {Binding is a typo?  Nevertheless, this does not work.  If i had the column as a type double, my original XAML works anyway.  Is your solution supposed to somehow show my column type string as formatted as $xx.xx?  The problem is that i cannot define the column as double, since they are null values that need to try and be inserted into it